# Facebook showing page not found when sharing link

Tags: facebook, wordpress, http-status-code-404, sharing

I'm sharing content from a website and every time I paste the link into Facebook it says 'page not found'.

Sometimes it works when I manually add the 'www.' in front of the URL in the address bar.

**EXAMPLE**

***Shows page not found:***

http://roundreviews.co.uk/reviews/speakers/native-union-monocle-speaker/

***Works when you manually place www. in front:***

www.roundreviews.co.uk/reviews/speakers/native-union-monocle-speaker/

I honestly have no I idea why it's doing this, any thoughts on how it can be fixed on the web side?

***Also...***

I have tried with the link below with both the www. and without yet it doesn't work with either of them, this is all very strange. This is the only link I have tried and it doesn't work with both:

www.roundreviews.co.uk/microphones/spark-digital-microphone/

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try putting the URL in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), and see what results you get back - there are likely errors in the OpenGraph definition.

Comment: See this related question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878721/facebook-share-link-returning-404-redirect-error-when-page-exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878721/facebook-share-link-returning-404-redirect-error-when-page-exists) - with the same suggested solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For me what it worked was to access the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), as Goose said.
I saw that the scrape was about 12 hours ago, looks like it fetches the first time and saves it as caché or whatsoever...
What it worked for me is to debug the url, then click "fetch new scrape information" after the previous information has been shown.
Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

For those running across this today, you might find that you also need to verify your domain and link it to your page.

To do this you need to

1. Set up a [Facebook Business Account](https://business.facebook.com/)
2. Add your page to the business account
3. Verify your domain (using DNS TXT or adding a page facebook gives you)
4. Under domains, connect your page as an asset of that domain