# Facebook cannot get title and description of my site

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

it's my [website](http://www.karyabee.com) when i copy a link from website to facebook, it suppose to get title/description and an image, but it's does not, i change title, and i checked description , keyword meta tags but still noting, how should i fix it, any ideas.

All Jobs in Afghanistan | Karyabee

[image]

Comment: Search in google `meta og:title` and other variations. You will find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your `<head>` to -> `<head prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns#">`

Now you can add between your `<head></head>` tags some values like;

For Title `<meta name="og:title" content="Your Site's Title"/>`

For Description `<meta name="og:description" content="Your Site's  Description"/>`

For Image `<meta name="og:image" content="path/to/your/image.jpg"/>`

and if you have facebook app id add it `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID">`

you can find some good practises on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

### EDIT & UPDATE

After make changes on your website codes; if facebook still showing old values on share window, you have to debug your url on Facebook Developer site.

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

You have 2 choices;

- Show existing scrape information (Fetches cached facebook resources from your website)
- Fetch new scrape information (Fetches new information from your site).

Comment: i have added this tags but still noting happans

Comment: @aGeniusfromAfghanistan could you please change your `<head>` to -> `<head prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns#">` also add if you have facebook app id add it `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID">`

Comment: thank you it's fixed now, but my server response is timing out. i need to fix my server speed. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar problem to one I had: [facebook share link returning 404 redirect error when page exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878721/facebook-share-link-returning-404-redirect-error-when-page-exists)

"When I add the pages to the delinter at developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it views the page fine, by rescraping it -- after which the links being shared work as well!"

For example when I pop in one of your urls to the debug tool such as http://karyabee.com/general-business/15740/logistics-assistant-commodity-tracking--32160 the initial response is: 'Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.' but once I clicked the 'fetch new scrape information' it populated the information available from the page - and pasting the link into a facebook share after this then shows the correct information.