# static pages hosted on bitbucket, i.e., <workspaceid>.bitbucket.io, posted on Facebook gives 404 error

Tags: facebook, bitbucket, http-status-code-404

I'm struggling with the following problem. I was writing a Facebook post, and I've attached a URL link to a static page hosted on Bitbucket. Once I posted, I found the URL link on the post did not work and gave a 404 error. After investigating the problem, I found this phenomenon happens with all static pages hosted on Bitbucket. Here are examples of static pages posted on Bitbucket, where I've confirmed the phenomenon

- https://lukforce.bitbucket.io/tm-planner/
- https://inic8.bitbucket.io/SoAIR19/
- https://joan6694.bitbucket.io/

### A similar but different case (link preview)

I found the following similar case,but it is the about the link preview attached to the post.

[facebook share link returning 404 redirect error when page exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878721/facebook-share-link-returning-404-redirect-error-when-page-exists)

By the way, the link preview properly works on these static pages.

### The same case but not solved yet

I found the following user has the same problem and posted it on the Atlassian community, but it still needs to be solved.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Cant-access-the-site-via-facebook-link-on-pc-and-android-mobile/qaq-p/1405020

Comment: The FB debug tool appears to read these URLs fine, it gets a 200 response code. I am guessing that this platform probably has problems with the additional tracking parameters Facebook automatically adds to outgoing links, and rejects the requests because of those(?)

Comment: Yes, Facebook appends fbclid to the URL, and the URL with the fbclid tag e.g., [https://lukforce.bitbucket.io/tm-planner/?fbclid=IwAR20i0z8GuuwIbm9bM58CJOtb105u5TNrM5h4o3KU84o4-9YoIQmrs-Lg0M](https://lukforce.bitbucket.io/tm-planner/?fbclid=IwAR20i0z8GuuwIbm9bM58CJOtb105u5TNrM5h4o3KU84o4-9YoIQmrs-Lg0M) works properly. Thus it seems Facebook is doing something more.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

```
curl -H "Referer:https://facebook.com/" -s https://akihisa-nq.bitbucket.io/ -w '%{http_code}\n'
```

404 Not Found

```
curl -s https://akihisa-nq.bitbucket.io/ -w %{http_code}
curl -H "Referer:https://facebook.net/" -s https://akihisa-nq.bitbucket.io/ -w %{http_code}
```

200 OK

GitHub pages doesn't reply 404 with the Referer header.
So, it is likely that Atlassian deny access from facebook.com.

I think it would be better to contact Atlassian or use an alternative service (ex. GitHub pages).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).